# Gulp - Get filename from src()

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

My goal is to retrieve the filename of a watched file and pass it to a `gulp-shell` task, which calls a `make` command and passes part of that filename as an argument.

The Gulpfile:

```
var gulp    = require("gulp");
var connect = require("gulp-connect");
var debug   = require("gulp-debug");
var shell   = require("gulp-shell");
var watch   = require("gulp-watch");


const PATTERN = "sass/**/*.scss"

// Default tasks to be executed
gulp.task("default", ["connect", "watch"]);

gulp.task("connect", function() {
    connect.server({
        root: ".",
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task("watch", function() {
    gulp.src(PATTERN)
        .pipe(watch(PATTERN))
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task("recompile", function() {
    // need {{file}}
    shell("compiling {{file}}");
});
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
.
..
gulpfile.js
sass/folder/file1.scss
sass/folder/folder2/file2.scss
sass/file3.scss
```

So, I change one of these .scss files (say, `sass/folder/folder2/file2.scss` and I would like the watch task to retrieve the filename, so I can execute something like `make id=file2.scss` after stripping the path down to the basename.

How do I best achieve this?
Ideally, the `"recompile"` task would only be called **when a file is changed**, but not on running `gulp` initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this with livereload, but i think you can do something like the example:

```
gulp.watch([PATTERN]).on("change", function (changeInfo) {
    connect.reload();
    console.log("Changed: " + changeInfo.path);
});
```